# linear system connections in python with scipy

Tags: python, signals, scipy

I am currently using Scipy's signal processing module scipy.signals to examine linear time invariant (LTI) systems.  I would like to know how best to connect the systems together.  For example, say I want to connection two systems

```
from scipy import signal

a = signal.lti([T1,0],[T1,1])
b = signal.lti(1,[T2,1])
```

in series.  I could do this by

```
cnum=signal.convolve(a.num,b.num)
cden=signal.convolve(a.den,b.den)    
c=signal.lti(cnum,cden)
```

to get the resulting system.  This notation is not very elegant though, especially if we are dealing with more than two systems.  Also, connecting two systems like this in parallel or feeding back a signal through another system is not as simple.

I see that I could install the python-control systems library, but I would be rather surprised if Scipy in some way does not include this functionality.

How can I interconnect LTI systems most elegantly?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304245/multiply-scipy-lti-transfer-functions, which has quite an elegant answer.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this in case anyone else comes along this.

You could develop a signal processing function as follows to join signals in series.

```
import scipy.signal as signal

def signal_processor(signals):
    """ Must pass an iterable containing sigal.lti signals """
    (result, signals) = (signals[0], signals[1:])
    for sig in signals:
        cnum = signal.convolve(result.num, sig.num)
        cden = signal.convolve(result.den, sig.den)
        result = signal.lti(cnum, cden)
    return result

 # Can then be used as follows:
 series_signal = signal_processor([sigA, sigB, sigC])
```

I'll have a look at extending this to building it out to handle other use cases as well.