# Multiply scipy.lti transfer functions

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following scipy.lti object that is basically an object representing a Laplace transform of an LTI system:

```
G_s = lti([1], [1, 2])
```

How to multiply such a transfer function with another one, such as i.e.:

```
H_s = lti([2], [1, 2])

#I_s = G_s * H_s <---- How to multiply this properly?
```

I guess I could do

```
I_s = lti(np.polymul([1], [2]), np.polymul([1, 2], [1, 2]))
```

But what if I want to do:

```
#I_s = H_s / (1 + H_s) <---- Does not work since H_s is an lti object
```

Is there an easy way to do this with scipy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "easy", you should consider deriving your own class from `lti`, implementing the necessary algebraic operations on your transfer functions. This is probably the most elegant approach.

Here's my take on the subject:

```
from __future__ import division

from scipy.signal.ltisys import TransferFunction as TransFun
from numpy import polymul,polyadd

class ltimul(TransFun):
    def __neg__(self):
        return ltimul(-self.num,self.den)

    def __floordiv__(self,other):
        # can't make sense of integer division right now
        return NotImplemented

    def __mul__(self,other):
        if type(other) in [int, float]:
            return ltimul(self.num*other,self.den)
        elif type(other) in [TransFun, ltimul]:
            numer = polymul(self.num,other.num)
            denom = polymul(self.den,other.den)
            return ltimul(numer,denom)

    def __truediv__(self,other):
        if type(other) in [int, float]:
            return ltimul(self.num,self.den*other)
        if type(other) in [TransFun, ltimul]:
            numer = polymul(self.num,other.den)
            denom = polymul(self.den,other.num)
            return ltimul(numer,denom)

    def __rtruediv__(self,other):
        if type(other) in [int, float]:
            return ltimul(other*self.den,self.num)
        if type(other) in [TransFun, ltimul]:
            numer = polymul(self.den,other.num)
            denom = polymul(self.num,other.den)
            return ltimul(numer,denom)

    def __add__(self,other):
        if type(other) in [int, float]:
            return ltimul(polyadd(self.num,self.den*other),self.den)
        if type(other) in [TransFun, type(self)]:
            numer = polyadd(polymul(self.num,other.den),polymul(self.den,other.num))
            denom = polymul(self.den,other.den)
            return ltimul(numer,denom)

    def __sub__(self,other):
        if type(other) in [int, float]:
            return ltimul(polyadd(self.num,-self.den*other),self.den)
        if type(other) in [TransFun, type(self)]:
            numer = polyadd(polymul(self.num,other.den),-polymul(self.den,other.num))
            denom = polymul(self.den,other.den)
            return ltimul(numer,denom)

    def __rsub__(self,other):
        if type(other) in [int, float]:
            return ltimul(polyadd(-self.num,self.den*other),self.den)
        if type(other) in [TransFun, type(self)]:
            numer = polyadd(polymul(other.num,self.den),-polymul(other.den,self.num))
            denom = polymul(self.den,other.den)
            return ltimul(numer,denom)

    # sheer laziness: symmetric behaviour for commutative operators
    __rmul__ = __mul__
    __radd__ = __add__
```

This defines the `ltimul` class, which is `lti` plus addition, multiplication, division, subtraction, and negation; binary ones also defined for integers and floats as partners.

I tested it [for the example of Dietrich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35782144/5067311):

```
G_s = ltimul([1], [1, 2])
H_s = ltimul([2], [1, 0, 3])
print(G_s*H_s)
print(G_s*H_s/(1+G_s*H_s))
```

While `GH` is nicely equal to

```
ltimul(
array([ 2.]),
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  6.])
)
```

the final result for GH/(1+GH) is less pretty:

```
ltimul(
array([  2.,   4.,   6.,  12.]),
array([  1.,   4.,  10.,  26.,  37.,  42.,  48.])
)
```

Since I'm not very familiar with transfer functions, I'm not sure how likely it is that this gives the same result as the sympy-based solution due to some simplifications missing from this one. I find it suspicious that already `lti` behaves unexpectedly: `lti([1,2],[1,2])` doesn't simplify its arguments, even though I'd suspect this function to be constant 1. So I'd rather not guess the correctness of this final result.

Anyway, the main message is inheritance itself, so possible bugs in the above implementation hopefully pose only a minor inconvenience. I'm also quite unfamiliar with class definitions, so it's possible that I didn't follow best practices in the above.

---

I eventually rewrote the above after [@ochurlaud pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304245/multiply-scipy-lti-transfer-functions/35809740?noredirect=1#comment61604159_35809740), that my original only worked for Python 2. The reason is that the `/` operation is implemented by `__div__`/`__rdiv__` in Python 2 (and is the ambiguous ["classical division"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)). In Python 3, however, there is a distinction between `/` (true division) and `//` (floor division), and they call `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__` (and their "right" counterparts), respectively. The `__future__` import first in the line of the above code triggers the proper Python 3 behaviour even on Python 2, so the above works on both Python versions. Since floor (integer) division doesn't make much sense for our class, we explicitly signal that it can't do anything with `//` (unless the other operand implements it).

One could also easily define the respective `__iadd__`, `__idiv__` etc. in-place operations for `+=`, `/=` etc., respectively.

Comment: I tried this (with Python3), and it didn't work for the `__div__` operator. Changing to `__truediv__` solved the problem. (idem for `__rdiv__`). Combining both answers provides a really nice subclass... I wish it was already in scipy...

Comment: @ochurlaud thanks a lot, you're perfectly right. I updated my post according to your comment. I don't have time to test it right now; please let me know if I made an error (I only added the update based on the PEP link).

Comment: This works fine on https://try.jupyter.org/ which uses Python 3.5.1 and scipy 0.17.1. On my own machine running Python 3.4.6 and scipy 0.18.0 I get `AttributeError: 'ltimul' object has no attribute 'impulse'` when trying to estimate the impulse response of the overall transfer function. Do you have an idea where this comes from?

Comment: @albert after a lot of head-scratching, it seems that `lti` is doing some black magic with `__init__` and `__new__` that messes with the above code. I could make it work by importing also `lti` `from scipy.signal.ltisys`, and inheriting from that too, i.e. using `class ltimul(TransFun,lti):`. Does that help? Does it not break the existing functionality?:)

Comment: @albert any luck?

Comment: There is and error in line:
           numer = polyadd(polymul(self.num,other.den),polymul(other.den,self.num))

it must be: 
polyadd(polymul(self.num,other.den),polymul(other.num,self.den))

Comment: @jfosoriot you're perfectly right, thank you very much for pointing it out! I took the opportunity and made the class python 2-3 compatible. Do let me know if you find any more bugs.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, Scipy does not seem to supply that functionality. An alternative is converting the LTI system into a Sympy rational function. Sympy allows you to easily expand and cancel polynomials:

```
from IPython.display import display
from scipy import signal
import sympy as sy

sy.init_printing()  # LaTeX like pretty printing for IPython


def lti_to_sympy(lsys, symplify=True):
    """ Convert Scipy's LTI instance to Sympy expression """
    s = sy.Symbol('s')
    G = sy.Poly(lsys.num, s) / sy.Poly(lsys.den, s)
    return sy.simplify(G) if symplify else G


def sympy_to_lti(xpr, s=sy.Symbol('s')):
    """ Convert Sympy transfer function polynomial to Scipy LTI """
    num, den = sy.simplify(xpr).as_numer_denom()  # expressions
    p_num_den = sy.poly(num, s), sy.poly(den, s)  # polynomials
    c_num_den = [sy.expand(p).all_coeffs() for p in p_num_den]  # coefficients
    l_num, l_den = [sy.lambdify((), c)() for c in c_num_den]  # convert to floats
    return signal.lti(l_num, l_den)


pG, pH, pGH, pIGH = sy.symbols("G, H, GH, IGH")  # only needed for displaying


# Sample systems:
lti_G = signal.lti([1], [1, 2])
lti_H = signal.lti([2], [1, 0, 3])

# convert to Sympy:
Gs, Hs = lti_to_sympy(lti_G), lti_to_sympy(lti_H)


print("Converted LTI expressions:")
display(sy.Eq(pG, Gs))
display(sy.Eq(pH, Hs))

print("Multiplying Systems:")
GHs = sy.simplify(Gs*Hs).expand()  # make sure polynomials are canceled and expanded
display(sy.Eq(pGH, GHs))


print("Closing the loop:")
IGHs = sy.simplify(GHs / (1+GHs)).expand()
display(sy.Eq(pIGH, IGHs))

print("Back to LTI:")
lti_IGH = sympy_to_lti(IGHs)
print(lti_IGH)
```

The output is:

[image: result]